# Recover DELL R815 from s2ram

Tags: suspend, wake-on-lan

My server is suspended to RAM using `s2ram`.

Pressing the power button does nothing.

How can I get it running again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run:

```
sudo ethtool -s eno1 wol g
```

before `s2ram`, then you can do:

```
wakeonlan f0:4d:a2:40:c6:fd
```

If you put this in `/etc/ethers`:

```
f0:4d:a2:40:c6:fd r815
```

then you can do:

```
wakeonlan r815
```